# Prevent Maple to evaluate before simplify a function

Tags: calculus, maple, computer-algebra-systems

I have been trying to find a domain of $f(x)=\frac{x}{\frac{(x+2)}{(x-3)}}$ using different kind of software ( its clear the domain of this function is $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{-2,3\}$ ). When I tried Maple , they directly changed to $f(x)=\frac{x(x-3)}{x+2}$ and its clear in this case the function is defined on 3.
I just want to know if there is a way to prevent maple from simplifying  the expression  before evaluating for some values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use exceptions:

f:=proc (x) 
    if x=-2 or x=3 then error "invalid x:",x 
    else x/((x+2)/(x-3)) 
    end if 
end proc:

Comment: Are you sure they will not simplify $\frac{x}{\frac{x+2}{x-3}}$

Comment: I am sure it will be simplified :D. But the test sends an error when $x=-2$ or $x=3$ and stops the computation (try it). Basically, it take the function $\frac{x(x-3)}{x+2}$ but impose by the test that $-2$ and $3$ are not in the domain.

I know it is ugly to do like this, but I don't know any other way.